# How to use class names with css module style names?

Tags: reactjs, css-modules

How to add the bootstrap class inside CSS module class in Reactjs.

I tried to add like the below, but it's not working:

```
<div className="col-sm-2 col-xs-12, {styles.divide}">
```

Comment: <div className="col-sm-2 col-xs-12, {styles.divide}">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the value of css module *style name* is string, you can simply do like this:

```
<div className={`col-sm-2 col-xs-12 ${styles.divide}`}>
```

The syntax `some string ${someVar}` is string [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in a cleaner way.

`<div className={["col-sm-2", "col-xs-12", styles.divide].join(' ')}>`

We are simply joining the elements of an array.